# How to select GeoJSON vector feature in Leaflet?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet

I've been using OpenLayers for years,instead of comparing OL & Leaflet libraries,I decided to use Leaflet for the job for now.

I have a GeoJSON data layer where I show point objects only.Just as I have used in OpenLayers,when user hovers(which is supplied with leaflet) & **toggle click** where I should change style of vector(s) (mostly color).I cannot find this event system in leaflet.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: This questions is answered in
[https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/183923/78343](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/183923/78343)