# How to keep vector layer on top of all layers despite toggling order?

Tags: leaflet

How do I keep a layer on top of my other layers despite the order it is toggled by the user? In this example, I've set up two layers named layerONE and layerTWO.

How do I keep my layerTWO (red square in this example) on top of layerONE at all times?

I tried this but it didn't work **(notice my bringToFront method)**:

```js
var layerONE = L.geoJson(layerOne).bindPopup('this is layer one!');

var layerTWO = L.geoJson(layerTwo, {
    style: {color: 'red'}
}).bindPopup('this is layer two!').bringToFront();

var overlays = {
    "Layer One": layerONE,
    "Layer Two": layerTWO
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);
```

[JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/htb5afed/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `bringToFront()` method changes the order of your layer only at the time it is executed.

When the user clicks on the Layers Control, your `layerONE` and `layerTWO` are added or removed at a later moment, and the `bringToFront()` effect is lost.

You would simply need to re-execute `bringToFront()` any time `layerONE` (or any other vector layer you may have, and that you want shown behind your `layerTWO`) is added to the map by the Layers Control.

Typically, listen to [`"overlayadd"` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-overlayadd) and bring to front your "top" vector layer again:

```js
map.on("overlayadd", function (event) {
  layerTWO.bringToFront();
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/htb5afed/3/

Comment: or "layeradd" when working with geometry layers, nice solution!